# Buffer overflow attack - returning to address on stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, buffer-overflow

I have an assignment that tells me that I need perform a buffer overflow by running code off the stack. I've been trying to do so but every time I replace the "ret" position of the stack with the location of the stack that I want the code to reside, it keeps seg faulting. If i replace the "ret" position with an address that exists in the physical .o file (like the physical assembly code) it works fine. Are you not allowed to return to positions on the stack? I'm confused how you can perform a buffer overflow with your own assembly code if you cannot return to a stack address... (btw, I'm using an IA32 little endian machine).

My steps:

1. overflow the 32 character buffer (put all FF)
2. overwrite the %ebp location (with the actual value stored there)
3. overwrite the "ret" spot above it with an address on the stack rather than an address in the assembly file
4. implant my assembly byte code (I make sure I add nop instructions at the start to ensure that it's done in multiples of 4 bytes)
5. run it

and this leads to a seg fault

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the stack pages are marked as executable; modern operating systems usually set the stack to be non-executable, and therefore will immediately segfault when you set the program counter to it.

Comment: I think for this assignment, we assume that the stack is marked as executable (otherwise they wouldn't give us an assignment like this). Any other ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the platform in many ways. Not all of your memory is executable, and on modern system there is usually an exclusive-or between memory that is writable and memory that is executable, just for those reasons. If you are using linux, you might want to build the stack with additional calls to `mprotect`, so you'll change the stack to be executable. This will require a more complex and constructed payload, but is doable.

Other option is that you still have problems in the arguments after the return address, which means you might "got lucky" with the call to the other function, as you didn't corrupt the stack, but when you injected your code, you did.

For further reading:

1. [NX bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit)
2. [mprotect](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect)